# Padding (walk) - Usage

Tags: word-usage

```
They are padding the street.
People are padding the street.
```

I came across this word recently. I'm not sure whether I understood the usage of it. The dictionary says  it means "to travel on foot; walk." If that's the case, can I use this word in all the places I where I used the word "walk" or "walking". Does the word fit in my above sample sentences?

Why can't just use the word 'walk' instead? How does the word pad differs from walk? What difference it makes?

Comment: Usually it takes a preposition-  one *pads **up, down, along, beside...** a path*

Comment: @Jim So I should say "People are padding along the street"?

Comment: @Jim Why can't just use the word 'walk' instead? How does the word pad differs from walk? What difference it makes?

Comment: Usually you use *pad* when you wish to call attention to a person's footwear or perhaps the softness of the ground a person is walking on.  I think I hear it most often in the context of small children wearing "footed" pajamas padding down the hall to their rooms.  Or maybe a bear padding down a forest trail. But the context should somehow relate to walking softly on "pads" of some sort.

Comment: @Jim So if the people are walking down a rough/bad road causally or may little tired, then I can use the pad?

Comment: From your description I don't think I'd use it there.  You might consider, *trudging* if you wish to emphasize their tiredness or *making their way* if you wish to emphasize the rough/bad road or  even *meandering* if you wish to emphasize their casualness.

Comment: @Jim I checked this word trudging but it looks it means exhausted and very tired and making heavy steps. In my case, I didn't mean this.

Comment: Ok, then don't use *trudging* but just as my three suggestions emphasized different aspects of walking, *padding*, I think, emphasizes the sound that is made (or sometimes the lack of sound) when walking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why can't I just use the word 'walk' instead?

Actually, you can use "walk" instead, and for everyday usage, you should. This definition of "pad" is technically valid, but it is specialized and rarely used.

> How does the word pad differ from walk? What difference does it make?

When I do see "pad" used this way, it is almost always referring to an animal, not a human. And not just any animal, but one with soft contact surfaces (i.e. pads) on the feet, such as dogs or bears. You would never use "pad" to describe the movement of a horse or chicken.

When used for a human, "pad" refers to a quiet and/or stealthy walk, not just any walk.

> Does the word fit in my sample sentences?

Not quite. If you do find a case where it makes sense to use pad, imagine how the sentence would be written with "walk" and then use the same form of "pad" in instead.

> * People are walking the street

is incorrect because it is missing a preposition. Instead, you might say

> People are walking/padding down the street

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot use *pad* everywhere you use *walk*. That's because...

You'd use padding in two cases -

> [padding (v)](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/PAD) - Walk heavily and firmly, as when weary, or through mud **OR** Walk quietly, esp. barefoot or with soft footwear.

It depends on the context how you want to use them.

However, take care that if you use it, it'd take [*adverb/preposition*](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/pad_2#pad_2__4) after it.

> She *padded across* the room to the window.

Answer (score 0):

No, IMHO you should not use the word 'padding' for walking at all.

Many reasons for this.

- People will not understand what you are talking about because padding
  has so many other meanings and not all of them are mentionable in a
  social context :)
- Padding means heavy walking, like a bear does. It is a specific gait.
- The use of padding  sounds like a person with a small vocabulary has opted for the word that first jumped to their mind rather than going for the more appropriate term.

Personally, I do not recommend using this word in the context of walking, especially since there are so many other specific words to be used for this act.